# Как перезаписать определенную строку в файле на указанную пользователем?

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит две строки, если первая из них есть в файле, то нужно перезаписать ее на вторую. Перерыл интернет, но, увы, не нашел работоспособного способа. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать (работаю со string и с потоками).

Comment: [Первая ссылка же](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9505085/13970074)

Comment: считываете файл, бьете его на строки, ищите совпадение строки, если находите, то заменяете ее на новую. В конце перезаписываете файл

Comment: Если строки **одинаковой длины** - то выставить указатель на начало строки в файле и выполнить запись. Если нет - то только перезаписью в новый файл...

Comment: @Harry ИМХО, такое следует делать только в случае, если файлы больших размеров (более 500Мб)

Answer (score 0):

считываете файл, бьете его на строки, ищите совпадение строки, если находите, то заменяете ее на новую. В конце перезаписываете файл

Если строки **одинаковой длины** - то выставить указатель на начало строки в файле и выполнить запись. Если нет - то только перезаписью в новый файл...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505085/replace-a-line-in-text-file